# If user inserts character other than Integer, the program should give him another chance to write an integer

Tags: java, exception

Ok, im trying to stop a user from enterring values other than Integers and smaller than 3 (first case). So far i have this code and the problem is, i cant make it stop, until the user enters correct values. i want to stup it and make him insert an integer into variable n and then can continue to add a value into variable  a   . how should i do this?
EDIT : new code

```
public class mnohouholnik  {
 public double a;
 public int n;
 public void main() {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     boolean error = false;

while ( ! error && n<3 ) { //you cant have a polygon which has only two angles

    try
    {

       System.out.println("Enter the number of angles in polygon");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        error = true;




    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e )
    { 
        System.out.println("Wrong value, try again");
        sc.nextLine();


    }

    try
    {

       System.out.println("Insert the length of the side :");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        error = true;



    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e )
    { 
        System.out.println("Wrong value, try again");
        sc.nextLine();


    }
}
```

}

}

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to set `error` to `false` if the input was ok and loop while `error && n<3`?

Comment: Which error you have exactly on mind?

Comment: You set the variable `error` to `true` if the user input is correct. This doesn't make much sense since the variable name is `error` and not `ok` (`validInput` like in the answer of @RealSkeptic).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    boolean validInput = false;

    while ( ! validInput ) {

        try
        {

            System.out.println("Please insert a number of angles in polygon:");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            validInput = true;

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException exception )
        { 
            System.out.println("Thats not an integer");
        }
    }
```

First, it assumes the input is not valid. It will repeat the input process while the input is not valid. The flag that tells it to stop is changed only after the `sc.nextInt()` call. If that call throws an exception, control will pass to the `catch` clause and `validInput` will not be changed. If it works OK and doesn't throw an exception, `validInput = true` will be executed, so the next time the `while` checks its condition, it will stop.

Comment: i tried this but it is running forever. as soon as i type a letter `a` , its writing those sentences until I reset it :/

Comment: @MarekKošík try adding `sc.next()` or `sc.nextLine()` in the `catch` clause. It seems that the scanner is not consuming the letter if there was an exception.

Comment: now i am trying to add a second variable, the length of one side. Still same principle, but I am stucked. User shouldnt be able to add a value into next variable until the first one is not correct but it seems it is not working. Im really ssorry for bothering you but could you also help mi with this one?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the new information in there. You can write something like "**Edit:** My new code is... and I have this problem:...".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    boolean valid = false;
    while(valid == false){

    //input code here 
    //if statement changing 'valid' to true, if the input is valid

    }
```